# Controlling spacing between two After positions

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am working with a graph with VertexLabels determined as follows:

```
    SetProperty[g, 
  VertexLabels -> {v_ :> 
     Placed[{Style[PropertyValue[{g, v}, VertexWeight], Black], 
       Style[PropertyValue[{g, v}, VertexWeight], Red], 
       Style[PropertyValue[{g, v}, VertexLabels], Blue]}, {Before, 
       After, After} ]}];
```

The double use of **After** means both

```
Style[PropertyValue[{g, v}, VertexWeight], Red]
```

and

```
Style[PropertyValue[{g, v}, VertexLabels], Blue]
```

occur overlapping one another (i.e. in the same spot)

Is it possible to have some space between these? How can it be implemented?

ETA: I could use Above, but I definitely want the two values to occur after the node and spaced out so they are legible. I tried the After  display to form a single pair (list of two elements), but could not get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
g = CycleGraph[3, VertexWeight -> {100, 200, 300}, 
  VertexLabels -> {v_:>{"A", "B", "C"}[[v]]}]
```

[image]

You can use symbolic positions `{After, Above}` and `{After, Below}`:

```
SetProperty[g, 
 VertexLabels -> {v_ :> 
    Placed[{Style[PropertyValue[{g, v}, VertexWeight], Black], 
      Style[PropertyValue[{g, v}, VertexWeight], Red], 
      Style[PropertyValue[{g, v}, VertexLabels], 
       Blue]}, {Before, {After, Above}, {After, Below}}]}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, replace `{Before, {After, Above}, {After, Below}}` with `{Before, {{1, 0}, {0, -1}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}}` to get the same picture.

The second approach is more flexible in that we can specify arbitrary number of labels and positions:

```
SetProperty[g, 
 VertexLabels -> {v_ :> 
    Placed[{Style[PropertyValue[{g, v}, VertexWeight], Black], 
      Style[PropertyValue[{g, v}, VertexWeight], Red], 
    ## & @@ (Style[PropertyValue[{g, v}, VertexLabels], #] & /@ 
     {Blue, Green, Orange, Red, Purple})},
   {Before, ## & @@ ({{2, 0}, {0, #}} & /@ Range[-2, 3, 1])}]}]
```

[image]